# setContentView in a MainActivity, which is in a "Android Library Project"

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-library

I have:

- one App without any Activities and a AndroidManifest.xml
- one "Android Library Project" with an Activity (MainActivity.java) and a Layout main.xml (res/layout)

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have registered the MainActivity Class, which is in the "Android Library Project" :

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I can start the App and I can debug the onCreate of MainActivity.

Now my problem.
When I try to set the content with ...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("main","layout", getPackageName());
        setContentView(ResourceId);
```

... I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3671)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3543)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3519)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:335)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:325)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
```

The variable "resourceId " has a promising value in it : 2130903046 , but it seems not referencing a valid resource ?

**Additional Info:**
I can set a LinearLayout, which is defined in the same main.xml without problems:

```
tbl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(getResourceId("main","id"));
```

no Error.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Why do you not using R.class?

Comment: I believe that, even though your activity resides in your library project, you must also define it in your other project. This has something to do with package names and all that

Comment: In my "Android Library Project" I have only the R.java generated under com.example.mylib. There is no R.java in my real packagename.

Comment: In my main app I do not have any package (Packagename). So I guess there should be no Packagename conflict

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all Helpers and sorry to waste your time. I found the problem.

The main.xml must reside in the Main App. Thats the only resource that has to be in the App. The rest (all resources) can be in the Library Project.